# Core Java Strings comparison

Tags: java, string

I am beginner in Java and i have a question while trying to learn Strings . In the below program

```
String st1="Test";
String st2="TEST";
String st3= st1.toUpperCase();

if(st3 == st2)
{
    System.out.println("Equals");

}
else
    System.out.println("Not Equals");
```

O/P for the above program displays as "Not Equals" where as i was expecting "Equals" Since "TEST" already exist in String Pool,  st3 should have pointed to already existing String rather than creating a new String.  Kindly explain the behavior. Thanks in advance

Comment: toUpperCase return new String object, not the one you expected from String pool
`return new String(result, 0, len + resultOffset);`

Comment: Use `.equals()` to compare strings

Comment: “==” operator compares the objects’ location(s) in memory, where as equals()  method is designed to compare the contents of 2 objects, and not their location in memory. In this case if you use obj.equals() you get expected result.